# Dockerfile node not installing dependencies

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15.3.0
ENV NODE_ENV=development
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN node -v
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install -g express
RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    container_name: api-mmogc-web
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "6510:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

but it don't install node dependencies on build

`docker-compose up --build`

image ls

```
root@xxx:/usr/src/app# ls -l
total 392
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    177 May  8 14:52 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1773 May  8 14:44 app.js
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     96 May  8 14:44 bin
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    160 May  8 14:44 config
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     96 May  8 14:44 constants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    582 May  8 14:44 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     96 May  8 14:44 middleware
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    224 May  8 14:44 migrations
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root    288 May  8 14:44 models
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    386 May  8 14:44 notas.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1332 May  8 14:44 nothing.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 371443 May  8 14:44 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1129 May  8 14:44 package.json
drwx------ 26  999 root    832 May  8 14:54 postgres_data
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     96 May  8 14:44 public
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    160 May  8 14:44 routes
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    160 May  8 14:44 seeders
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     53 May  8 14:44 setup-test.js
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    192 May  8 14:44 utils
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    160 May  8 14:44 views
```

Edited.
According to comments.

commenting volumes installed dependencies but now my changes on the host are not reflected on `image`

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: api-mmogc-web
    build: .
    # volumes:
    #   - .:/usr/src/app
```

Comment: Your `volumes:` hide almost everything the Dockerfile does; the host's `./node_modules` directory (if any) will completely replace what the `RUN npm install` step does.  Delete the `volumes:` block from the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze awesome, it worked. Now docker installed all the dependencies, but, because I deleted `volumes:` from `docker-compose.yml` changes on file on the host are not reflected inside `image`. How can I do that?

Comment: Re-run `docker-compose build` once you've tested your application in your host Node environment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the `volumes` from the `docker-compose.yml`. It's tricky to install `node_modules` while using volumes.

There are several ways to do that. I'd suggest you add this step to your dockerfile:

```
# Installing node_modules to another folder and load it from there
RUN ["mkdir", "/modules"]
ADD ["./package.json", "/modules"]
WORKDIR /modules
RUN npm install
ENV NODE_PATH=/modules/node_modules

# Set the WORKDIR
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Edit: You shouldn't use `COPY` and `WORKDIR` together. Because when you use both of them, you are overriding created `/usr/src/app` folder with `COPY` command once more. So, you should also remove the `COPY` if you are gonna use this trick

Comment: Both `WORKDIR` and `COPY` (and `ADD`) will create the directory if it doesn't already exist; you don't need to explicitly `RUN mkdir ...` it.

Comment: No, mkdir is for `node_modules` however, I didn't see the COPY step. He should remove that. And of course there shouldn't be `node_modules` in the source folder.